# rake task OR bundle exec rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, bundler

(Note: I found the same issue on stackoverflow but it didn't solve my issue so I'm going to provide more information about.)

I set up an RoR environment. It contains rvm, ruby, ruby on rails and bundler. Everything seems to be correct.

I switch into this folder which contains a RoR application and try to reset the database

```
katarina@katarina-VirtualBox:~/RubymineProjects/prototyp1$ rake db:reset
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- bundler/setup

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
katarina@katarina-VirtualBox:~/RubymineProjects/prototyp1$
```

Error: "Cannot load such file -- bundler/setup"
On the other side "bundle exec rake db:reset" works as expected.

Here my environment values:

I. ruby installation:

> katarina@katarina-VirtualBox:~/RubymineProjects/prototyp1$ rvm list
>
> rvm rubies
>
> ruby-1.9.3-p194 [ x86_64 ]
>    =*  ruby-1.9.3-p429 [ x86_64 ]
>      ruby-2.0.0-p195 [ x86_64 ]

So "ruby-1.9.3-p429" is my current and default ruby version.

II. used gemset

> katarina@katarina-VirtualBox:~/RubymineProjects/prototyp1$ rvm gemset
>   list
>
> gemsets for ruby-1.9.3-p429 (found in
>   /home/katarina/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429)
>      (default)
>      global
>
> => prototyp1

So I'm using prototyp1 gemset created inside the current ruby version.

III. contained gems:

NOte: $GEM_HOME points to the proper gemset and gem list returns an item containing the bundler.

```
katarina@katarina-VirtualBox:~/RubymineProjects/prototyp1$ cd $GEM_HOME
katarina@katarina-VirtualBox:~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@prototyp1$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.2.8)
actionpack (3.2.8)
activemodel (3.2.8)
activerecord (3.2.8)
activeresource (3.2.8)
activesupport (3.2.8)
addressable (2.3.4, 2.3.3)
arel (3.0.2)
bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
better_errors (0.9.0)
binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
bootstrap-sass (2.3.2.0)
builder (3.0.4, 3.0.3)
bundler (1.2.0)
cancan (1.6.10)
capybara (2.1.0)
chunky_png (1.2.6)
coderay (1.0.9)
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.6.2, 1.4.0, 1.3.3)
compass (0.12.2)
cucumber (1.3.2)
cucumber-rails (1.3.1)
daemons (1.1.9)
database_cleaner (1.0.1)
debug_inspector (0.0.2)
devise (2.2.4)
diff-lcs (1.2.4, 1.1.3)
email_spec (1.4.0)
erubis (2.7.0)
eventmachine (1.0.3)
excon (0.16.10)
execjs (1.4.0)
factory_girl (4.2.0)
factory_girl_rails (4.2.1)
faraday (0.8.7)
figaro (0.6.4)
fssm (0.2.9)
gherkin (2.12.0)
hashie (2.0.5)
heroku (2.35.0)
heroku-api (0.3.8)
hike (1.2.3, 1.2.1)
httpauth (0.2.0)
hub (1.10.6)
i18n (0.6.4)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (3.0.1, 2.1.4, 2.1.2)
json (1.8.0, 1.7.5)
jwt (0.1.8)
launchy (2.3.0, 2.2.0)
libv8 (3.11.8.17 x86_64-linux, 3.3.10.4 x86_64-linux)
mail (2.4.4)
mime-types (1.23, 1.19)
mini_portile (0.5.0)
multi_json (1.7.7, 1.4.0, 1.3.6)
multipart-post (1.2.0)
netrc (0.7.7)
nokogiri (1.6.0, 1.5.5)
oauth (0.4.7)
oauth2 (0.8.1)
omniauth (1.1.4)
omniauth-facebook (1.4.1)
omniauth-linkedin (0.1.0)
omniauth-oauth (1.0.1)
omniauth-oauth2 (1.1.1)
omniauth-twitter (0.0.17)
orm_adapter (0.4.0)
pg (0.14.1)
polyglot (0.3.3)
quiet_assets (1.0.2)
rack (1.5.2, 1.4.5)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.3, 1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.2, 0.6.1)
rails (3.2.8)
railties (3.2.8)
rake (10.0.4, 10.0.2, 0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.12.2, 3.12)
ref (1.0.5)
rest-client (1.6.7)
rolify (3.2.0)
rspec (2.11.0, 2.0.1)
rspec-core (2.13.1, 2.11.1, 2.0.1)
rspec-expectations (2.13.0, 2.11.3, 2.0.1)
rspec-mocks (2.13.1, 2.11.3, 2.11.2, 2.0.1)
rspec-rails (2.13.2, 2.11.0, 2.0.1)
rubygems-bundler (1.1.0)
rubyzip (0.9.9)
rvm (1.11.3.5)
sass (3.2.9, 3.2.3, 3.2.1)
sass-rails (3.2.6, 3.2.5)
simple_form (2.1.0)
sprockets (2.1.3)
sqlite3 (1.3.7, 1.3.6)
therubyracer (0.11.4, 0.10.2)
thin (1.5.1, 1.5.0)
thor (0.18.1, 0.16.0)
tilt (1.4.1, 1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.14, 1.4.12, 1.4.10)
tzinfo (0.3.37, 0.3.35, 0.3.33)
uglifier (2.1.1, 1.3.0)
warden (1.2.1)
webrat (0.7.1)
webrick (1.3.1)
xpath (2.0.0)
```

Why am I getting the error when executing rake?
Is it an "old-fashioned" way to execute rake tasks? It is recommended to execute "bundle exec .." rather than "rake ..."?

Thank you in advance.
golbie

Answer (score 3):

It is strongly recommended to execute tasks with `bundle exec`. It ensures the task to be executed in the context of current bundle.

Comment: You can use [bundler-exec](https://github.com/gma/bundler-exec) or [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh)'s bundler plugin to prepend `bundle exec` automatically.